# Create select box in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had a category table.It was include the id, name and remark fields.

I want to create a categories select box.So,I create a select box in laravel with foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ Form::select('category_id', array($category->id => $category->name))}}
@endforeach
```

But I got two select box. What I was wrong? I want one select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an array of categories to `Form::select()`:

```
{{ Form::select('category_id', $categories) }}
```

If you put it in a loop, it will create as many selects as categories you have.

Build that array in your model, repository or (even!) controller before passing it to your view.